# Unpacking a list-column of multi-row tibbles while preserving the number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, tibble

I have a tibble in which one column is a list of tibbles. Some tibbles in
this list have more than one row. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(tibble)
tmp <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
   1,  tibble(a=1,   b=2),
   2,  tibble(a=4:5, b=6:7))
```

which produces

```
> tmp 
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      x y               
  <dbl> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [1 x 2]>
2     2 <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

I want to create a tibble that has the same number of rows as `tmp` and
that expands the list-column into as many columns as necessary. In the 
example, I want

```
      x      a1      a2      b1      b2
  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       1      NA       2      NA
2     2       4       5       6       7
```

I had thought to do this with some combination of `unnest()` and `pivot_wider()`, or perhaps `flatten()`,  but I cannot quite get it to work. What is the best way to do this?

In this example, the tibbles in the list-column never have more than two rows. But in my real list-columns, some tibbles have one row, some have two, and some have more than two. So I am looking for a solution that works when the tibbles in the list-column have any arbitrary number of rows.

Comment: How many columns you have inside y? just approximation

Comment: Each tibble in the list-column will have about 3 columns. And whether the actual number is 2 or 3 or 4, all tibbles in the list-column will have the same number of columns. Thank you.

Comment: This does not provide the exact output though: `tmp %>% 
  unnest(y) %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from =x,values_from = a:b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution using `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
unnest_wider(tmp, y) %>% 
      unnest_wider(a, names_repair = ~gsub('...', 'a', .)) %>% 
      unnest_wider(b, names_repair = ~gsub('...', 'b', .))

New names:
* `` -> ...1
...
New names:
* `` -> ...1
* `` -> ...2
# A tibble: 2 x 5
      x    a1    a2    b1    b2
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1    NA     2    NA
2     2     4     5     6     7
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. With other data frames, it may help to replace `gsub('...', 'b', .)` with `gsub('...', 'b', ., fixed = TRUE)` so that `...` doesn't match any three-character substring in the output data frame.